# Show <tfoot> footer always at the bottom

Tags: css, html

I have following **html** which is used to render a **PDF** file, I need to render the `<tfoot>` section always at the bottom of every page even if the content of the page are small.

```
<div class="pdf-position-top pdf-content-center">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="print-banner">
            <span class="banner-text-repeat">Some Text</span>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    @RenderSection("TableBody", required: true)
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="pdf-content-center">@RenderBody()</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <!--START print-banner top-->
          <div class="print-banner">
            <span class="banner-text-repeat">Some Text</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Use your PDF generator functions to apply footer.

Comment: I am using EO.Pdf (Essential Objects) to convert html to pdf

Answer (score 1):

[From documentation of header/footer](https://www.essentialobjects.com/doc/pdf/htmltopdf/header.aspx)

```
EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.Options.HeaderHtmlFormat = '<div class="print-banner">
        <span class="banner-text-repeat">Some Text</span>
    </div>'
```